# Version history of attachment(doc) in Info path form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, version-history, comparison

We have a custom info-path form with attachment option. Now there is a requirement of checking the version history of the attached document in this form.

Actually the requirement is to use the **compare** functionality, that come when open a version of any document from a library..

Any suggestion how can I achieve it !

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand correctly:

You have an InfoPath form with an attachment in the form? In this case there is no versioning of the attachment.
If you browse your library where the form is stored in explorer view (the XML files) and open one in editor (notepad) there would be a encoded XML string representing the document.

In this case I don't see a simple solution. If you need to go with this approach you could try to create versions of the document for yourself.

Or do you have a link pointing to a document in your InfoPath form? And you want to access the version history of this doucment?

In this case you might be able to link the SharePoint Version History of the document.

Comment: The current scenario is the first one, where attachment is saved in info-path form.....   but i can change the way to link (but don't know yet to show the document link in info-path form)....  Also will it support in SharePoint 2016 as well!

Comment: Do you have any workflow engine (ie. nintex) installed? With Nintex you can extract the document and save it to a document library. Otherwise I would suggest that you create a library where users upload documents into folders and link the folder to the infopath.

Comment: No Nintex. but if I go with the separate document library, would it be possible to link individual document with a particular form !

Comment: If the documents are in the library before the form is filled, you could use a datasource with a recurring list for the library, so one could select the documents. Or you just use a text field and let them link the documents there (like copy&pase the url)?